Controller failure on ZFS pool
I am running ZFS on an old Sun Fire X4170M2 connected to Sun StorageTek 6140 expansion shelves (i.e. JBOD). We had a hardware failure this morning.
This is the current state of our pool:
  pool: tww
 state: UNAVAIL
status: One or more devices is currently being resilvered.  The pool will
        continue to function, possibly in a degraded state.
action: Wait for the resilver to complete.
  scan: resilver in progress since Wed Jul 10 07:09:46 2024
    1.03T scanned out of 13.6T at 15.2M/s, 240h24m to go
    14.0G resilvered, 7.56% done
config:

        NAME                         STATE     READ WRITE CKSUM
        tww                          UNAVAIL      0     0     0  insufficient replicas
          raidz2-0                   ONLINE       0     0     0
            c3t2000001862811E34d0    ONLINE       0     0     0
            c3t2000001862811D10d0    ONLINE       0     0     0
            c3t20000018628136B3d0    ONLINE       0     0     0
            c3t2000001D3806860Fd0    ONLINE       0     0     0
            c3t20000018623532A3d0    ONLINE       0     0     0
          raidz2-1                   ONLINE       0     0     0
            c3t2000001862813768d0    ONLINE       0     0     0
            c3t20000018621CBE00d0    ONLINE       0     0     0
            c3t2000001862E73AEDd0    ONLINE       0     0     0
            c3t20000024B668227Fd0    ONLINE       0     0     0
            c3t2000001862811E78d0    ONLINE       0     0     0
          raidz2-2                   ONLINE       0     0     0
            c3t2000001862811DD5d0    ONLINE       0     0     0
            c3t20000018621CD261d0    ONLINE       0     0     0
            c3t2000B45253638B36d0    ONLINE       0     0     0
            c3t200000186281377Ed0    ONLINE       0     0     0
            c3t2000001862E72611d0    ONLINE       0     0     0
          raidz2-3                   UNAVAIL    729     0     0  insufficient replicas
            c3t20000018623555B2d0    ONLINE       0     0     0  (resilvering)
            spare-1                  FAULTED      0     0     0
              c3t20000018623534ACd0  FAULTED      0     4     0  too many errors
              c3t2000001862818A66d0  ONLINE       0     0     0  (resilvering)
            c3t200000186281371Cd0    FAULTED    296   292     0  too many errors
            c3t2000001862353317d0    FAULTED    409     2     0  too many errors
            c3t2000001862813664d0    ONLINE       0     0     0  (resilvering)
          raidz2-4                   UNAVAIL      2     0     0  insufficient replicas
            spare-0                  FAULTED      0     0     0
              c3t20000018623534F4d0  FAULTED     77   143     0  too many errors
              c3t20000024B6DB516Ed0  ONLINE       0     0     0  (resilvering)
            c3t2000001862811D1Ad0    FAULTED      2     3     0  too many errors
            spare-2                  FAULTED      0     0     0
              c3t20000018621CBDC5d0  FAULTED      3    65     0  too many errors
              c3t2000001862353444d0  ONLINE       0     0     0  (resilvering)
            c3t200000186235333Fd0    ONLINE       0     0     0
            c3t20000018621CBD96d0    ONLINE       0     0     0
          raidz2-5                   ONLINE       0     0     0
            c3t20000018628136EBd0    ONLINE       0     0     0
            c3t20000024B6D181E7d0    ONLINE       0     0     0
            c3t200000186235467Fd0    ONLINE       0     0     0
            c3t20000018628136A1d0    ONLINE       0     0     0
            c3t20000018621CC64Dd0    ONLINE       0     0     0
...
        logs
          mirror-9                   ONLINE       0     0     0
            c9t5000A72A3007D78Dd0    ONLINE       0     0     0
            c17t5000A72A3007C7E8d0   ONLINE       0     0     0
        cache
          c3t5000A72030067DECd0      ONLINE       0     0     0
          c3t5000A72030067DF0d0      ONLINE       0     0     0
          c3t5000A72030067DEEd0      ONLINE       0     0     0
          c3t5000A72030067DEFd0      ONLINE       0     0     0
        spares
          c3t2000001862353444d0      INUSE     currently in use
          c3t2000001862818A66d0      INUSE     currently in use
          c3t20000024B6DB516Ed0      INUSE     currently in use
          c3t2000001D38FCC34Ed0      AVAIL   

What can I expect the state of the pool to be in when the controller is replaced? Is the pool lost? I would expect the resilver to continue with the three spare drives as sufficient replicas would now be available. The resilver is stuck now because of insufficient replicas.

Doesn't look too worrying. You need to wait for the resilver to finish anyway, and replacing the defective controler should bring the missing volumes back. Just don't panic...

Replaced the controller and the pool became usable. Letting the three spares resilver then will resilver back to non-spare drives. Thanks.
